# Convert html special characters to japanese characters

Tags: angularjs

I have a data from api that returns a html like entities, my question is how can I convert those to japanese characters by using filter in angular JS. These are sample characters that is returned.

```
$scope.name = '&#29694;'
```

what I want to happen is like

```
 .filter('unsafe', function($filter) {
     return function(val) {
         // translate here
     };
 })
```

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23230680/angularjs-displaying-html-unicode

Answer (score 1):

Solved this by using ng-bind-html and ng-sanitize injected in the module.